# web::Payload::next() hangs when websocket connection is interrupted

Tags: rust, websocket, actix-web

I write a websocket server without using Actix actors and struggle with weird hanging on `web::Payload::next()` when connection is aborted without sending `close` message from client. Here is a simplified example:

```rust
async fn handle_connection(
    req: HttpRequest,
    stream: web::Payload,
) -> ActixResult<HttpResponse> {
    let mut res = ws::handshake(req.head())?;
    let (tx, rx) =
        mpsc::channel::<Result<Bytes, ActixError>>(FRAME_BUFFER_CAPACITY);

    spawn_local(handle_frames(stream));

    res.message_body(BodyStream::new(rx).boxed())
        .map(HttpResponse::from)
        .map_err(ActixError::from)
}

async fn handle_frames(mut stream: web::Payload) -> Result<()> {
    while let Some(chunk) = stream.next().await { // Hangs here.
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?